# Proving a property of the $\sigma$-algebra of the product of two countable-cocountable $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X = Y$ be uncountable and define $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}$ to be the countable-cocountable $\sigma$-algebras on $X, Y$ respectively. Let $C = \sigma(A \times B)$. Prove that for each subset $E \in C$, there exist $A, B$ in $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}$ countable such that either $E \subseteq (A \times Y) \cup (X \times B)$ or $E^c \subseteq (A \times Y) \cup (X \times B)$.

My idea is to define $D$ as the collection of all such subsets of $C$, prove that $D$ contains $A_1 \times B1$ for each $A_1 \in \mathcal{A}, B_1 \in \mathcal{B}$ and then show that $D$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

I am able to prove that $D$ is a $\sigma$ algebra, and I can show that in the case $A_1, B_1$ are either both countable or cocountable, $A_1 \times B_1$ is in $D$. How do I do it for the case that exactly one of them is cocountable?

Something that may be useful is $(A_1 \times B_1)^c = (A_1^c \times Y) \cup (X \times B_1^c) \cup (A_1^c \times B_1^c)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A_1$ is countable and $B_1$ is cocountable.
Then it follows that
$$
A_1\times B_1\subseteq A_1\times Y\subseteq(A_1\times Y)\cup(X\times B)
$$
where $B\in\mathcal B$ is an arbitrary countable set (e.g., $B=\emptyset$).
This shows that $A_1\times B_1\in D$.